# "java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe" when using Hibernate with Mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am facing a very unfrequent problem but much troubling.

```
     java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3832)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2471)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2031)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1832)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
```

I am reading a lot about this but not able to figure out how come this error appear with this setting of hibernate :

```
         <hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.generate_statistics">false</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">100000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>

    <!-- Assume test is the database name -->



</session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

I dont want to use connection pooling to be precise. So I gave 0 value to both max and min pool size. What can be the cause of this error?

Comment: Setting `0` in both is probably not good. Just to be safe, comment (`<!-- ... -->`) all those three annotations that have `c3p0`.

Comment: Won't that give default value to c3p0 then as per https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool ? Will commenting out c3p0 disable connection pooling?

Comment: I dont think so (if you removed all c3p0 properties, why would hibernate enable it?), but I'm not 100% on this. Do you have any c3p0 jar on the classpath? If so, try removing it.

Comment: I dont have any specific jars for that. Anyway I am commenting out that section. But still I am not able to figure out the cause of broken pipe exception. What can be the cause of that issue?

Comment: I think I got some broken pipe exceptions sometimes ago. I think thats just network unstability. If thats the case, theres nothing you can do about that, other than configuring your hibernate to restablish the connection as soon as it breakes.

Comment: Okk....by the way, in case I set c3p0 max value as 0, then how hibernate will manage pool size? Any idea?

Comment: Nope, no Idea... Would have to setup some tests to see if we can guess. Did you try anything? Still struggling with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

well... this is a SocketException. It probably has nothing to do with the properties that you mentioned. You should rather focus on your data source parameters. Maybe it's incorrect connection url or jndi name?

Comment: The error comes rarely like once a month. So I don't think its due to url problem. But one thing I want to ask. Hibernate uses its own pooling in case any other external party is not provided and cant be disabled. So, should we use external party like c3p0 ? Is there any way to disable pooling anyway?